# Netbeans won't install on Windows 10

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to install Netbeans 8.2 Java EE, but whenever I start the installer it quits after configuring it. I am trying to install it on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: What operating system are you installing it on?

Comment: I'm installing it on windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not going to make sense at all, but do you happen to have the "God Mode" item on your desktop?  Take it off the desktop (delete it, move it somewhere else, whatever).  I have no idea why, but it worked for me: I found the solution in this bug report - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269988

I do hope this helps you, too.

Comment: It works with me, been trying so many times, but GOD Mode folder in my desktop causing the netbeans 8.2 not to work. So i put it somewhere and yes the netbeans was installed successfully

Comment: Really a weird bug. And that bug report comment `But these guys are not responding to any bugs or problems. Is netbeans development dead?` makes me have second thoughts if I want to install netbeans at all

Comment: The only explanation for this bug is, that netbeans tries to create a empty file on the desktop for whatever reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Java issue, which was came up due to recent windows 10 update, that started treated differently for GodMode folder/shortcut.
This has been already fixed - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179014 
You can verify the fix in early access build of JDK8 update 152, which is available [here](http://jdk.java.net/8/)

We have verified the issue only with GodMode, do let us k now if there are any other scenarios that can cause such similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this because: I had a different issue which I was unable to find addressed anywhere, this question appears near the top of a web search for "NetBeans 8.2 ee won't install on Windows 10", and someone else may have the problem I had.

My NetBeans install was almost immediately crashing with the following error:

> An unexpected exception happened in thread main
>
> Exception: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for
>   class javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory cannot be created

In my Windows 10 *System Properties -> Environment Variables -> System Variables*, I had a previously created _JAVA_OPTIONS variable values using `-Xbootclasspath/a` to append some jar files to the end of the bootstrap class path. These files are used with some work I'm doing with the Oracle BI Publisher plug-in for Microsoft Word.

**As soon as I renamed the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable to something else, my NetBeans installation started normally and completed with no issues.**

After NetBeans installation, I reset the name of this variable back to _JAVA_OPTIONS, and discovered that the values I have for this System Variable cause NetBeans launch to crash.  (Which does not completely make sense to me since I am only appending these files/classes to the class path, and not overwriting.)

Regardless, I'll have to go back to the drawing board for my work with the BI Publisher plug-in; but at least I can use NetBeans now!

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall any Java installations along with NetBeans, and install Java with NetBeans (bundle) from the Oracle website.

I had the same issue, and then installed the bundle, works perfectly.

Comment: Nope it didn't work. It still quit after configuring the installer